# How to define multiple patterns in php glob()

Tags: php, glob

My code to get all images from a directory

```
$dirname = "uploads/";

$images = glob("{$dirname}*.png, {$dirname}*.jpeg, {$dirname}*.jpg, {$dirname}*.gif");

foreach($images as $image) {

    echo "<img src='{$image}' class='files_main'>";

}
```

This works for one type of image but fails with multiple please give the syntax of defining multiple patterns in the glob().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314061/php-glob-more-than-one-pattern-at-a-time any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `GLOB_BRACE` constant

> GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'

e.g.

```
$dirname = 'uploads/';
glob("$dirname*.{png,jpeg,jpg,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php