# PHP GLOB more than one pattern at a time

Tags: php, design-patterns, glob

code:

```
$matches = glob("$searchword*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE)  ;
```

that works, but i also have $secondword,  so i read [How to define multiple patterns in php glob()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899453/how-to-define-multiple-patterns-in-php-glob)

so i tried

```
$matches = glob("{$searchword},{$secondword}*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE)  ;
$matches = glob("{$searchword,$secondword}*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE)  ;
$matches = glob("{$searchword*.txt},{$secondword*.txt}",  GLOB_BRACE)  ;

$matches = glob("$searchword*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE) && ("$secondword*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE);
$matches = (glob("$searchword*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE) && ("$secondword*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE));
```

results in invalid syntax

what im trying to do: list files via glob that are smilar to a $filename
is it possible to glob files that are similar to $filename?

references:
https://www.cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/

Comment: so what's the problem here?

Comment: results in invalid syntax

Comment: you can use multiple formats not multiple names. means cannot place multiple `$searchword,$secondword` . but can check multiple format like `{png,jpeg,jpg,gif}`. check the link answer carefully

Comment: every `$matches` will overwrite the previous, each needs a unique var name

Comment: ok is it possible to glob files that are similar to $filename?

Comment: Alive to Die  take a look at the answer below by Being Suny, it works but does not work in variables

Comment: Yes it is works with variable also, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I've multiple **txt** files on my directory. Here I used `glob` with `GLOB_BRACE` and it perfectly showing the expected result to me.

```
$a = 'import_start_';
$b = '22_02_18_country_';
$m= glob("{{$a},{$b}}*.txt",  GLOB_BRACE);
 // OR // 
// $m= glob({".$a.",".$b."}*.txt", GLOB_BRACE);              
// OR //

print '<pre>';
print_r($m);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
 [0] => import_start_date.txt
 [1] => 22_02_18_country_list.txt
)
```

Comment: that what i have in line two but using varibles instead of import_start and 22_02_18  results in crash

Comment: thanks i was doing that then i refreshed this page and noticed you had done it too. good owrk but why did others on this page say its not possbile.

Comment: @Nance , glad it works for you, bye the way you can accept it by clicking on the TICK mark :)